# Angularjs ng-pattern isn't working for me

Tags: regex, angularjs

I have been trying to find an answer on StackOverflow for my problem, but nothing seems to fix it.

Here is what I have:

```
<label>Portal Code</label>
<input type="text" name="portalcode" class="form-control" ng-model="dropoff.tfWeb" id="tfWeb" maxlength="8" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/" ng-disabled="report != null">
<pre>Errors: {{portalcode.value.$error}}</pre>
```

I am trying to add an `ng-pattern` directive that ensures only alphanumerics can be entered into the input.  I have tried not using double quotes, I have tried using the `\w` shortform for alphanumerics.  I've tried using a `*` instead of `+`.  I'm at a loss now.  No matter what I've changed it to, though, my `{{portalcode.value.$error}}` does not print out an error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What about just `{{portalcode.$error}}`?

Comment: That did not work, same results currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if you wrap it in a form and use the form to access the `portalcode`:
http://jsfiddle.net/xtfcg447/1/

Comment: This did the trick.  It wasn't very clear that I had to wrap it in a form.  I was hoping I could use the directive without wrapping it in a form.  Guess not, oh well!  Thank you.

Comment: I think the way it works is that it looks for the closest `ngForm` with a name attribute and "hooks" onto it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/"`

Here is the example in plunker:
http://embed.plnkr.co/UeCrkhQ6tBEj60MbsKXx/preview